# Incomplete loading from Google Cloud to Qlikview

Tags: sql, google-cloud-storage, qlikview

We're trying to load a several million row table from Google Cloud into Qlikview but every time we've run the script to load it, the execution window stops prematurely loading only a fraction of the total table. Does anyone know if this is an issue with Google Cloud, Qlikview, or anything else and how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: How are you loading the data into Qlikview?

Comment: Any error messages? Freezes?